# MPEG-1 Layer 3 suddenly became extremely quiet

Tags: 16.04, codecs, mint

After an update yesterday on Linux Mint 18.1 Serena some video and audio files suddendly became quiet.

- They are extremely quiet, but not 100% silent. I can hear wispering.
- All of them are encoded as "MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3)".
- All applications (Xplayer, Chrome) are affected.
- Other files and streaming audio are just the same good as before.
- Problem files are still good, if played on another devices.

I do not appreciate this kind of magic. Please help me diagnose and fix the codec.

**UPDATE** Seems it was a problem within hardware. All the problem files were mono, all the others - stereo.

Comment: Please check your /var/log/apt history and determine which relevant packages were upgraded.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks. But I need some keywords, to know what "relevant" is

Comment: I've just found `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (63.0.3239.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 64.0.3282.119-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)` there. But downgrade to previous version has no effect regarding the problem.